# using pandas.DataFrame.melt() with seaborn.barplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, bar-chart, grouped-bar-chart

So, I have some data in two columns in a Pandas DataFrame:

```
Actual  Predicted
0   2.8 2.854729
1   2.2 3.081473
2   4.2 3.211041
3   2.9 2.951905
4   3.4 3.211041
5   3.3 2.838533
6   3.5 3.194845
7   3.1 3.000493
8   2.8 3.016689
9   2.8 3.032885
```

I want to learn to plot my data with three common libraries. They all seem to be based on one another, but the implementation is very different. So far I have achieved the same plot using Pandas and Matplotlib. The Pandas way was very easy, the matplotlib unreasonably complicated (just an opinion).

```
# Plot with Pandas DataFrame.plot()
df.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(16,10))

# Plot with matplotlib 
plt.figure(figsize=(16,10))
plt.bar(df.index - .35/2, df.iloc[:,0], .35, label='Actual')
plt.bar(df.index + .35/2, df.iloc[:,1], .35, label='Predicted')
plt.legend()
```

Now I am trying to figure out Seaborn, using their docs, but I'm having a hard time figuring out what my x and y values should be. In my mind:

- x - df.index Because I want all of the datapoints to be arranged
  along the x axis
- y - I want the 'y' values to be twofold: Actual AND Predicted. No
  idea how to make that happen.
- hue - df.columns, since I want to have one bar that representsactual, and one that represents predicted

However, this doesn't work at all, and neither do any of these attempts:

```
sns.barplot(x=df.index, y=df.columns, data=df) 

sns.barplot(data=df)
```

My intuition is that I need to use the DataFrame.melt() function to get my data into long format for better plotting, but I tried this:

```
df2 = df.melt(var_name='Type', value_name='Measurement')
df2


Type    Measurement
0   Actual  2.800000
1   Actual  2.200000
2   Actual  4.200000
3   Actual  2.900000
4   Actual  3.400000
... ... ...
85  Predicted   2.903317
86  Predicted   3.211041
87  Predicted   2.870925
88  Predicted   3.146257
89  Predicted   3.211041
```

But this screws up my chance getting the correct bars right next to each other, since it lumps all the "Actual" values together, separate from all the "Predicted" Values.

I tried it anyway in hopes it would group the bars together correctly somehow. I used the template that comes from the examples below the docs page for seaborn.barplot, and got `ValueError: Could not interpret input 'Measurement'`:

```
sns.barplot(x=df.index, y='Measurement', hue='Type')
```

So my thought is, this all comes down to using the melt function correctly, but I'm at a total loss at this point. My eyes are now bleeding because the documentation is so confusing. I was told that seaborn was the easiest way to plot things, and it's turning out to absolutely be the hardest.

I THINK my data should look like this:

```
    Type        Measurement
0   Actual      2.800000
    Predicted   2.903317
1   Actual      2.200000
    Predicted   3.211041
... ... ...
```

And then I could follow the sample code for seaborn.barplot():

```
sns.barplot(x=df.index, y="Measurement", hue="type", data=df)
```

Or at least that's what I hope...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trick is to reset the index before melting... this will be your `x` parameter:

```
df_melted = df.reset_index().melt(id_vars='index')

#     index   variable     value
# 0       0     Actual  2.800000
# 1       1     Actual  2.200000
# 2       2     Actual  4.200000
# 3       3     Actual  2.900000
# 4       4     Actual  3.400000
# 5       5     Actual  3.300000
# 6       6     Actual  3.500000
# 7       7     Actual  3.100000
# 8       8     Actual  2.800000
# 9       9     Actual  2.800000
# 10      0  Predicted  2.854729
# 11      1  Predicted  3.081473
# 12      2  Predicted  3.211041
# 13      3  Predicted  2.951905
# 14      4  Predicted  3.211041
# 15      5  Predicted  2.838533
# 16      6  Predicted  3.194845
# 17      7  Predicted  3.000493
# 18      8  Predicted  3.016689
# 19      9  Predicted  3.032885

sns.barplot(data=df_melted, x='index', y='value', hue='variable')
```

[out]

[image]